# Casson's knot invariant

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Informally speaking, the Casson invariant counts half the number of conjugacy classes of representations of the fundamental group of a homology $3$-sphere $M$ into the group $\SU(2)$. My question is for a knot $K$ inside $M$, what does the Casson's knot invariant count? Am I right to think that it counts half the the number of conjugacy classes of representations of the fundamental group of the knot complement $M\setminus K$ into the group $\SU(2)?$ Can anyone provide any heuristic and maybe a reference?

Comment: What is your definition of the "Casson's knot invariant"? Perhaps you mean the invariant mentioned here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164357/casson-invariant and that is related to $\Delta_K''(1)$? Otherwise such a count of (traceless) representations was studied by Lin in his paper "a knot invariant by representation spaces". https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/lin2.pdf and is related to the signature of the knot.

Comment: For knots in $S^3$ it's called the type-2 finite-type (Vassiliev) invariant.  It's a count of round circles that intersect the knot in 5 points, such that if any two points are adjacent in the circle parametrization then they are not adjacent in the knot parametrization.  I had a summer student create a demonstration here:  https://sean564.github.io/top/  you'll need to click on a knot, or if you have a WebGPU enabled browser (and a GPU with a lot of cores) you can enter any knot you like.

Comment: @AnthonyConway, my definition is from Akbulut & McCarthy, I believe up to a sign it's the same one as the overflow link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this directly answers your question, but section 3 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938389900116) by Morita might have something useful. He describes the Casson knot invariant in terms of the Alexander polynomial and then relates it to the regular Casson invariant.